# if value is found on a column write data on the same row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

**im trying to create a code where im using a userform to verify if a value is already in column a. then if that value is found it will make me write or copy the specific values from a different worksheet. im doing this so i can avoid the conflict error when 2 or more users saved this workbook.i have this code but everytime 2 or more users save its giving them saving error pls help.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()


If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
Workbooks("Satisfaction.xlsm").AcceptAllChanges
Workbooks("Satisfaction.xlsm").Save

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lngWriteRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Answers")

lngWriteRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If lngWriteRow < 1 Then lngWriteRow = 1

ws.Range("B" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D25").Value
ws.Range("C" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D26").Value
ws.Range("D" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D27").Value
ws.Range("G" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E37").Value
ws.Range("H" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E45").Value
ws.Range("I" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E53").Value
ws.Range("J" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E61").Value
ws.Range("K" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E70").Value
ws.Range("L" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E79").Value
ws.Range("M" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E87").Value
ws.Range("N" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E96").Value
ws.Range("O" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E104").Value
ws.Range("P" & lngWriteRow) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E112").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D25").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D26").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("D27").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E27").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E37").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E45").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E53").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E61").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E70").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E79").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E87").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E96").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E104").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E112").Select
Selection.ClearContents

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Intro").Visible = xlSheetVisible
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Thank you for taking the exam"
Workbooks("Satisfaction.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below line before the last line of your code.

```
Workbooks("Satisfaction.xlsm").AcceptAllChanges
Workbooks("Satisfaction.xlsm").Save
```

Comment: If you want you can but as per your code these lines should go just before you call the save method

Comment: Hi i tried it but still not working. this time only 1 person receives the error everytime 2 people is trying to save. im thinking if i can do it like if the value is found in column a then the other data that needs to be inputed should be written in the same row as the value